# How can I find projects across multiple open-source code repositories?

Tags: open-source, code-search-engine

There are lots of open-source code repositories - [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net), [Google Code](http://code.google.com/), [Project Kenai](http://projectkenai.com), etc.

Is there a one-stop place where I can find, discover, or search for open-source projects across all of these repositories?  Or do I have to visit all of them to find something I'm interested in?

**Edit:** I should specify that I'm interested in searching project descriptions, not just lines of code.  I'd like to answer, "Is there an existing tool for doing X?" - and is it actively maintained, and other higher-level questions like that.

Answer (score 1):

[Krugle](http://opensearch.krugle.org) allows you to search across open source code, open source projects and even SCM check-in comments. What's not to love?

Comment: @Dale - I've just updated it, Krugle has changed a lot since '09!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [freshmeat.net](http://freshmeat.net/)?

Comment: doesn't this only search freshmeat projects?

Comment: It a catalog where any project can be registered.

Comment: the fact that you have to register a project there first makes it kind of limited then

Comment: Kind of, yes. But 45,413 projects sounds pretty good to me and since anyone can register a project and many authors of OS projects register them themselves, you are likely to have a pretty good pre-filtered catalog.

Comment: Hmm. It seems that some people really hate either me or freshmeat.

Answer (score 0):

There are several directories for open source software, e.g:

- http://www.opensourcesoftwaredirectory.com/
- http://osload.com/

Search google for "open source directory" to find others.